# Can't read some swift Syntax

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm learning swift, but sometimes when i look at answers to questions and some of them are impenetrable. How do I implement the following?

> If you call - [UITableView setFrame:] from - [UITableViewController
>   viewDidAppear:], it works:
>
> ```
> - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
> {
>     [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
> }
> ```
>
> In order to avoid having black bars on each side of the table view,
>   set the background color of the application's main window to white:
>
> ```
> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
> ```

Do I override view did appear? what is with the `-(void)`, and why is the `self.tableView` line in brackets, and what's the final line represent?

Comment: Before Swift, we developed with ObjectiveC. This is what it looks like :)

Comment: It's Objective C, one thing you are going to want to do, is learn how to read it, even at a basic level, as many of the existing answers and solutions are written in ObjC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Alladinian mentioned, it's Objective-C. Another language you can use for iOS development.
You can get basics of language for example on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)

Answering your question, in swift it will look like:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
}
```

and

```swift
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I definitely agree with you, but it missing in original code as well